# How These 2 Almost Same code are different?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11

This Code is giving error Heap-Use-After-Free

```
for (auto it = mp.begin();it != mp.end();it++)
{
    if(it->second+ttl<=currentTime)
    {
        mp.erase(it);
    }
}
```

But this code

```
for (auto it = mp.begin();it != mp.end();)
{
    if(it->second+ttl<=currentTime)
    {
        mp.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Does Not give ans error.
Can you please explain why?
Both look basically the same to me.
Please Help

Comment: Both invoke undefined behavior. `mp.erase(it);` invalides `it`.

Comment: @mch But the second one is not giving error Why is that we have writteen mp.erase(it) in that too??

Comment: @26_ChirayuAggarwal Not giving an error is one possible outcome of undefined behavior

Comment: @TedLyngmo No its working perfectly I passed all the testcases using 2nd one

Comment: @26_ChirayuAggarwal That's also possible with undefined behavior. What kind of container is it? That's important to be able to answer the question fully.

Comment: @TedLyngmo its a unordered_map<string,int> mp;

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, there are no guarantees that two fragments of code that are "essentially the same" will give the same outcome.

Answer (score 4):

The first one erases the element at `it` which invalidates `it` in all standard containers. Doing `it++` afterwards makes the program have undefined behavior.

The second one *may* work depending on which container you use.

- If you for example use a `*map`, it's ok because `it++` returns the iterator's current value but steps it internally to point at the next element. That iterator will be unaffected by the `erase`.
- If you use a `vector` it has undefined behavior because the iterator after `it++` will be invalidaded by the `erase`.

To make it work with any type of standard container, assign the iterator returned by `erase` to `it`.

```cpp
for (auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end();) {
    if (it->second + ttl <= currentTime) {
        it = mp.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

If you have an `unordered_map`, then since C++20, I recommend using
[`std::erase_if (std::unordered_map)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if) instead:

```cpp
std::erase_if(mp,
    [&](const auto& data) { return data.second + ttl <= currentTime; });
```

Comment: Thank You! Just one more question Why is it ok for map but not for vector?

Comment: @26_ChirayuAggarwal  You're welcome. I added explanations for that

Comment: *"That's the idiomatic approach"* Idiomatic approach depends on containers too: [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for non-`map`/`set`.

Comment: @Jarod42 True - I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, after erase, 'it' becomes `mp.end()` for map or undefined for `unordered_map`, giving the error.
And in the second case, uses `mp.erase(it++)`, which makes 'it' points to next element in `mp` after erase.

Comment: Why does it becoming mp.end() gives error it should just come out of the loop also if there is only one element in the map then 2nd would also make it mp.end() Can you please explain it in more detail